# Deleting duplicate text in a cell in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016, excel-2002

I was wondering how to remove duplicate names/text's in a cell. For example

```
Jean Donea Jean Doneasee 
R.L. Foye R.L. Foyesee 
J.E. Zimmer J.E. Zimmersee 
R.P. Reed R.P. Reedsee  D.E. Munson D.E. Munsonsee
```

While googling, I stumbled upon a macro/code, it's like:

```
Function RemoveDupes1(pWorkRng As Range) As String
'Updateby20140924
Dim xValue As String
Dim xChar As String
Dim xOutValue As String
Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
xValue = pWorkRng.Value
For i = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
    xChar = VBA.Mid(xValue, i, 1)
   If xDic.exists(xChar) Then
   Else
      xDic(xChar) = ""
      xOutValue = xOutValue & xChar
   End If
Next
RemoveDupes1 = xOutValue
End Function
```

The macro is working, but it is comparing every letter, and if it finds any repeated letters, it's removing that.

When I use the code over those names, the result is somewhat like this:

```
Jean Dos
R.L Foyes
J.E Zimers
R.P edsDEMuno
```

By looking at the result I can make out it is not what I want, yet I got no clue how to correct the code.

The desired output should look like:

```
 Jean Donea
 R.L. Foye 
 J.E. Zimmer
 R.P. Reed
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Input

With the input on the image:

[image: ![Input names]

### Result

The `Debug.Print` output

[image: Output]

### Regex

A regex can be used dynamically iterating on the cell, to work as a Find tool. So it will extract only the shortest match. `\w*( OUTPUT_OF_EXTRACTELEMENT )\w*`, e.g.: `\w*(Jean)\w*`

The Regex's reference must be [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128681/7690982).

### Code

```
Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Mid(Txt, 1)), Separator)(n - 1)
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' error handling code
    EXTRACTELEMENT = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub test()

Dim str As String
Dim objMatches As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'New regexp
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Row = 1 To lastrow
    str = Range("A" & Row)
    F_str = ""
    N_Elements = UBound(Split(str, " "))
    If N_Elements > 0 Then
        For k = 1 To N_Elements + 1
            strPattern = "\w*(" & EXTRACTELEMENT(CStr(str), k, " ") & ")\w*"
            With objRegExp
                .Pattern = strPattern
                .Global = True
            End With
            If objRegExp.test(strPattern) Then
                Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
                If objMatches.Count > 1 Then
                    If objRegExp.test(F_str) = False Then
                        F_str = F_str & " " & objMatches(0).Submatches(0)
                    End If
                ElseIf k <= 2 And objMatches.Count = 1 Then
                    F_str = F_str & " " & objMatches(0).Submatches(0)
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    Else
        F_str = str
    End If
    Debug.Print Trim(F_str)
Next Row

End Sub
```

> Note that you can Replace the `Debug.Print` to write on the target
>   cell, if it is column B to `Cells(Row,2)=Trim(F_str)`

### Explanation

#### Function

You can use this **UDF**, that uses the [Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) to obtain the element separated by spaces (" "). So it can get every element to compare on the cell.

#### Loops

It will loop from 1 to the number of elements `k` in each cell and from `row` 1 to `lastrow`.

#### Regex

The Regex is used to find the matches on the cell and Join a new string with the shortest element of each match.

Answer (score 0):

This solution operates on the assumption that 'see' (or some other three-letter string) will always be on the end of the cell value. If that isn't the case then this won't work.

```
Function RemoveDupeInCell(dString As String) As String
Dim x As Long, ct As Long
Dim str As String

'define str as half the length of the cell, minus the right three characters
str = Trim(Left(dString, WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Len(dString) - 3) / 2, 0)))

'loop through the entire cell and count the number of instances of str
For x = 1 To Len(dString)
    If Mid(dString, x, Len(str)) = str Then ct = ct + 1
Next x

'if it's more than one, set to str, otherwise error
If ct > 1 Then
    RemoveDupeInCell = str
Else
    RemoveDupeInCell = "#N/A"
End If

End Function
```